# ElasticSearch: a gibberish query still returns results. How to ensure quality?

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I implemented a custom filter which uses the EdgeGram tokenizer. The problem I face is that whether I search for something relevant or total garbage I get a large number of hits. I suspect that this is due that fact that I'm using an EdgeNgram tokenizer. How can I ensure the quality of the search results and have ES return no matches for low quality results?

Comment: what does your custom tokenizer look like? In order to understand your problem, it would be good if you could explain with a scenario (i.e. what's your mapping, data, expected output, actual output etc). As it stands your question is very broad!

Comment: When asking an ElasticSearch question it is wise to add your mapping, index settings, the query you are using and an example bit of data you're working with. This way people won't guess what you're doing wrong but rather tell you definitely.